# Interpolate camera rotation over many keyframes smoothly

Tags: mathematics, animation, camera, quaternion

I have a defined set of rotation/position keyframes that I want a camera to animate between smoothly.  Handling the position is easy enough using cubic bezier curves (and just auto-generating the control points between each keyframe).  But after a day of research I'm still having a lot of trouble figuring out how to handle rotation similarly.

My first thought was that there must be a similar way to do it using bezier curves, except applied to quaternions instead of 3d vectors.  I found a bunch of research papers on the subject, but as is so often the case with research papers, actually implementing them is another story entirely (and frustratingly, source code is never provided).  So if anyone with experience in this stuff could give me some direction as to the best approach here I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Do you know about quaternion slerp? If not you should check it out.  It's a "linear" interpolation but I think it ought to suit your needs.

Comment: I suggest googling Quaternion slerp functions. Spherical linear interpolation. Here is a good article on it http://number-none.com/product/Understanding%20Slerp,%20Then%20Not%20Using%20It/

Comment: My understanding is that slerp only deals with interpolating between two quaternions.  What I'm trying to do is smoothly interpolate along a path of potentially many quaternions.  And I'd like to have the angular velocity remain continuous when going from one rotation to the next, etc.  So I don't think using slerp alone is enough.